# GSAP Scrolltrigger PIN not working properly in nextjs

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-animations, gsap

From my code below, If I comment out the pin: true property, the code works normally but the container that wraps the sections I expect to scroll horizontally are not sticky to the top. If I uncomment the pin: true, all the container (trigger) will not be visible.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import OverlayMenu from "./OverlayMenu";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";

function MainContent({ overlayRef }) {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
  useEffect(() => {
    // alert(document.querySelector(".main__content").offsetWidth)
    const sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".section");
    gsap.to(sections, {
      xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
      ease: "none",
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".main__content",
        scrub: 1,
        markers: true,
        start: "top top",
        // // snap: 1 / (sections.length - 1),
        end: "+=" + document.querySelector(".main__content").offsetWidth,
        pin: true,
      },
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main__content__wrapper w-[calc(100%_-_80px)] h-screen ml-20">
      <div className="w-full relative h-screen">
        <OverlayMenu overlayRef={overlayRef} />
        {/* <div className="w-full h-screen bg-black"></div> */}
        <div className="main__content w-[300%] bg-purple-700 h-screen flex  flex-nowrap">
          <div className="section w-full h-screen- bg-red-500">1</div>
          <div className="section w-full h-screen- bg-blue-500">2</div>
          <div className="section w-full h-screen- bg-yellow-500">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainContent;
```

Comment: I later discovered the problem is from the strict mode of react 18, which causes the page to do multiple mounting.

The solution is to either disable the strict mode (if, that won't affect your application), or you can aswell, use a react state to check if the page has rendered, then you create instance of the gsap timeline, then when it want to do the second mounting, you prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Step back the version to **3.8.0**

```
yarn add gsap@3.8.0
```

OR

```
npm install gsap@3.8.0
```

You can read more here:
https://greensock.com/forums/topic/30747-scrolltrigger-in-nextjs-build-not-working-reliably/#comment-153675

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import OverlayMenu from "./OverlayMenu";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";

function MainContent({ overlayRef }) {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
  const [hasRendered, setHasRendered] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    // ******This will set the state of hasRendered when the page render so as to keep track of the rendering steps *******
    setHasRendered(true);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ******* I added the conditional statement here to only create the instance of the gsap timeline ONLY after the page has rendered*******
    if (hasRendered) {
      // alert(document.querySelector(".main__content").offsetWidth)
      const sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".section");
      gsap.to(sections, {
        xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
        ease: "none",
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".main__content",
          scrub: 1,
          markers: true,
          start: "top top",
          // // snap: 1 / (sections.length - 1),
          end: "+=" + document.querySelector(".main__content").offsetWidth,
          pin: true,
        },
      });
    }
  }, [hasRendered]); //******** Dont forget the dependencies array too */

  return (
    <div className="main__content__wrapper w-[calc(100%_-_80px)] h-screen ml-20">
      <div className="w-full relative h-screen">
        <OverlayMenu overlayRef={overlayRef} />
        {/* <div className="w-full h-screen bg-black"></div> */}
        <div className="main__content w-[300%] bg-purple-700 h-screen flex  flex-nowrap">
          <div className="section w-full h-screen- bg-red-500">1</div>
          <div className="section w-full h-screen- bg-blue-500">2</div>
          <div className="section w-full h-screen- bg-yellow-500">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainContent;
```